# Sum and dividing by total number of repeats using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

Suppose I have a dataframe as such:

```
d<- data.frame (type=c("rna","rna","rna"), value = c(1,2,3) )
d2 <- data.frame (type=c("dna","dna"), value = c(20,30) )
df <- rbind (d,d2)
```

It looks like this:

```
  type value
1  rna     1
2  rna     2
3  rna     3
4  dna    20
5  dna    30
```

Now I need to summarize by type, that is aggregate all types by summing AND dividing it by the total occurence.  For example in the above example it would be for rna (1+1+3) / 3 and dna (20+30)/2 however currently I can only to get it to sum as such,

```
library(dplyr)
    df %>%
        group_by(type) %>%
        summarise_all(sum) %>%
        data.frame()
```

the above code produces

```
  type value
1  rna     6
2  dna    50
```

whereas what I really want is this

```
  type value
1  rna     2
2  dna    25
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to divide by the number of rows in each group (`n()`)

```
df %>% 
   group_by(type) %>%
   summarise(value = sum(value)/n())
```

which is otherwise the `mean`

```
df %>%
  group_by(type) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value))
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   type  value
#   <fct> <dbl>
#1 rna       2
#2 dna      25
```

Comment: yah, haha that right. thank you! Did not realize that but the the /n part is useful.